# Image fit to window

Tags: css, image, html

I wanted to fit this image (galeria.jpg) to the window but It adds scrolling panel at the bottom and the border over the menu. It shouldn't go like this...
HTML CODE:

```
<body>
<div class="tlo">
    <div class="logo">
        <img src="logo.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="galeria" >
    <img src="galeria.jpg" />
</div>

<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="link">STRONA GŁÓWNA</a></li>
        <li><a href="link">KONTAKT I LOKALIZACJA</a></li>
        <li><a href="link">ZAKRES CZYNNOŚCI NOTARIUSZA</a></li>
        <li><a href="link">OPŁATY W KANCELARII</a></li>
        <li><a href="link">PRZYDATNE INFORMACJE</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color:#ffffff; 
    padding:0px; 
    margin:0px; 
}
.logo{
    position:absolute; 
    margin-left:-400px; 
    left:50%;
}
.tlo{
    height:230px;
    width:100%;
    background: #e0e0e0;
}
.galeria{ 
    width:100%;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SfG3A/

Comment: Ive added a jsfiddle but is it possible for you to upload the image somewhere so we can see the size of the image on the jsfiddle. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
.galeria img{ 
    width:100%; // Remove this and add below style
    max-width:100%;
    vertical-align:bottom; // to remove the white space below the image
}
```

When you give width `100%` it takes the width of the image and when you give max-width it restricts the image to have the maximum width of its parent element.

Comment: It doesn't work... Here is my website: www.wnp.com.pl/kancelaria

Comment: sorry my bad. Please check my updated answer. I was missing an `img` in the css.

Comment: Thanks it works! But just look at the white border at the bottom of the image I don't know what about this It should disapeear but it doesnt...

Comment: to remove the white space below the image use this `.galeria img{float:left;}` `.galeria{overflow:hidden;}`. This is not the best solution i think, but atleast should solve your issue.

Comment: @user3452920 don't use the above styles in the comment i gave before, the ideal solution will be to use this `.galeria img{vertical-align:bottom;}`

Comment: @user3452920 Please use the `vertical-align` style and let me know if that works.

Comment: Great... Please close this by accepting my answer if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `overflow-x: hidden` to the div who contain the galleria.jpg

http://jsfiddle.net/SfG3A/1/